# How to uploading duplicate tags at some picture for azure custom vision?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-custom-vision

I have a question for azure custom vision. I have a custom vision project for object detection. 
And I use the python SDK to create the project (see that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/python-tutorial-od). 
But I found something wrong in the process of uploading. 
For example, there is a picture that has 3 persons in this picture. So I tag 3 same class “person” in this picture. But after uploading, I just found 1 "person" tagged in this picture at the custom vision website. 
But the other class is fine, such as can also have "person", "car", and "scooter" at this picture. It looks like that can only have single same class at the picture.

I tried to use python SDK (see that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/python-tutorial-od) to upload my picture and tag information.

```
A0_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A0")
A1_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A1")
A2_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A2")

A0_image_regions={
"0001.jpg":[0.432291667,0.28125,0.080729167,0.09765625],
"0001.jpg":[0.34765625,0.385742188,0.131510417,0.135742188],
"0001.jpg":[0.479166667,0.385742188,0.130208333,0.135742188],
"0003.jpg":[0.19921875,0.158203125,0.083333333,0.099609375]
}
```

The above code can see that I uploaded three "A0" class in 0001.jpg. But in the GUI interface on the website, I can only see that one "A0" class exists above 0001.jpg finally. Is there anything solution that can solve this problem?

---

Based on cthrash code. I made some changes to the code to make it work.
Here is the modified code:

```
A0_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "TestA")
A1_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "TestB")
A2_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "TestC")

A0_image_regions = {
    A0_tag.id : [
                ("2300.png",[0.787109375,0.079681275,0.068359375,0.876494024]),
                ("0920.png",[0.2109375,0.065737052,0.059570313,0.892430279]),
                ("0920.png",[0.291015625,0.061752988,0.05859375,0.894422311]),
    ]
}

A1_image_regions = {
        A1_tag.id : [
                    ("2000.png",[0.067382813,0.073705179,0.030273438,0.878486056]),
                    ("2000.png",[0.126953125,0.075697211,0.030273438,0.878486056]),
                    ("2000.png",[0.184570313,0.079681275,0.030273438,0.878486056]),
                    ("2000.png",[0.232421875,0.079681275,0.030273438,0.878486056]),
    ],
}

A2_image_regions = {
        A2_tag.id : [
                ("1400.png",[0.649414063,0.065737052,0.104492188,0.894422311]),
                ("2300.png",[0.602539063,0.061752988,0.106445313,0.892430279]),
                ("0920.png",[0.634765625,0.067729084,0.124023438,0.88247012]),
                ("0800.png",[0.579101563,0.06374502,0.04296875,0.888446215]),
    ],
}



regions_map = {}
for tag_id in A0_image_regions:
    for filename,[x,y,w,h] in A0_image_regions[tag_id]:
        regions = regions_map.get(filename,[])
        regions.append(Region(tag_id=A0_tag.id, left=x, top=y, width=w, height=h))
        regions_map[filename] = regions

for tag_id in A1_image_regions:
     for filename,[x,y,w,h] in A1_image_regions[tag_id]:
        regions = regions_map.get(filename,[])
        regions.append(Region(tag_id=A1_tag.id, left=x, top=y, width=w, height=h))
        regions_map[filename] = regions


for tag_id in A2_image_regions:
     for filename,[x,y,w,h] in A2_image_regions[tag_id]:
        regions = regions_map.get(filename,[])
        regions.append(Region(tag_id=A2_tag.id, left=x, top=y, width=w, height=h))
        regions_map[filename] = regions




tagged_images_with_regions = []
for filename in regions_map:
    regions = regions_map[filename]
    with open("<your path>" + filename, mode="rb") as image_contents:



        tagged_images_with_regions.append(ImageFileCreateEntry(name=filename, contents=image_contents.read(), regions=regions))
upload_result = trainer.create_images_from_files(project.id, images=tagged_images_with_regions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created `A0_image_regions` but are overriding the key whenever you have more than one bounding box for any given image.  So that's not going to work.

But perhaps more importantly, you need to call the trainer with the image as the primary objects, with all the associated image regions lumped together.  In other words, in you're example `0001.jpg` has three instances of `A0`, but it may also have instances of `A1` and/or `A2`, and this would neet to be a single ImageFile entry. So I'd modify the sample along the lines of the following:

```
A0_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A0")
A1_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A1")
A2_tag = trainer.create_tag(project.id, "A2")

image_regions = {
    A0_tag.id : [
        ("0001.jpg", [0.432291667,0.28125,0.080729167,0.09765625]),
        ("0001.jpg", [0.34765625,0.385742188,0.131510417,0.135742188]),
        ("0001.jpg", [0.479166667,0.385742188,0.130208333,0.135742188]),
        ("0003.jpg", [0.19921875,0.158203125,0.083333333,0.099609375])
    ],
    A1_tag.id : [] # add images/bounding boxes for A1
    A2_tag.id : [] # add images/bounding boxes for A2
}

regions_map = {}
for tag_id in image_regions:
    for filename,[x,y,w,h] in image_regions[tag_id]:
        regions = regions_map.get(filename,[])
        regions.append(Region(tag_id, left=x, top=y, width=w, height=h))
        regions_map[filename] = regions

tagged_images_with_regions = []
for filename in regions_map:
    regions = regions_map[filename]
    with open(base_image_url + filename, mode="rb") as image_contents:
        tagged_images_with_regions.append(ImageFileCreateEntry(name=filename, contents=image_contents.read(), regions=regions))

upload_result = trainer.create_images_from_files(project.id, images=tagged_images_with_regions)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, these codes can work. And I made some modifications to make the loop work. The codes save behind my question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to mark only one tag `person` for 3 persons in a picture, but it's no sense, not an issue. Actually, the tag is marked to the picture, not to a pixel area shown a person in the picture.

Therefore, the tag `person` just helps to detect a fact there is one person at least after trained the model, not `car` or `scooter`. If you want to detect different person, the requires that you need to add three tags like `person1`, `person2` and `person3` for the three different persons in a picture.

Please refer to the wiki page [`Object detection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection) and its reference links to know more details about the principle of machine learning and deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not change anything else in the sample code, then it is trying to upload image "0.001.jpg" with the one bounding box three times, and the last two uploading fails, because they are duplicate images with your first uploaded image.

Please upload the "0.001.jpg" just once with three bounding boxes, or upload the image first and then the three boxes.